# Can't find field data in Sharepoint list using SOAP

Tags: sharepoint, soap

I'm stuck trying to find some data in a Sharepoint list.

I have the list ID, using the List Service "GetList" method I can see that the field I'm looking for is attached to the list.  When I try to use "GetListItems" the field isn't there.

I've been assuming that it means the field I want isn't in the default view, but even when I define the view fields explicitly or change the query, I still can't find the data.  What should I do?

Here are some of the attempts I've made, none show the fields I'm looking for.

Method 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns0:Body>
<ns1:GetListItems>
     <ns1:listName>{1A8A3DF2-E5D0-4DDE-B31A-CCC2FB7DA90F}</ns1:listName>
     <viewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_Title"/>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_Project_x0020_Description"/>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_Style_x0020_number_x0020_quantit"/>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_Requirement"/>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_First_x0020_order_x0020_entry_x0"/>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_MKT_x0020__x0025__x0020_Completi"/>
        <FieldRef Name="_ows_MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"/>
     </viewFields>
     <ns1:rowLimit>10</ns1:rowLimit>
  </ns1:GetListItems>
</ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Method 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns0:Body>
<ns1:GetListItems>
     <ns1:listName>{1A8A3DF2-E5D0-4DDE-B31A-CCC2FB7DA90F}</ns1:listName>
     <viewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Description"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Style_x0020_number_x0020_quantit"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Requirement"/>
        <FieldRef Name="First_x0020_order_x0020_entry_x0"/>
        <FieldRef Name="MKT_x0020__x0025__x0020_Completi"/>
        <FieldRef Name="MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"/>
     </viewFields>
     <ns1:rowLimit>10</ns1:rowLimit>
  </ns1:GetListItems>
</ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Method 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns0:Body>
  <ns1:GetListItems>
     <ns1:listName>{1A8A3DF2-E5D0-4DDE-B31A-CCC2FB7DA90F}</ns1:listName>
     <Query>
        <Where>
           <Gt>
              <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
              <Value Type="Counter">0</Value>
           </Gt>
        </Where>
     </Query>
     <ns1:rowLimit>10</ns1:rowLimit>
  </ns1:GetListItems>
</ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

All three methods list all fields in the default view (ignoring my filters/query) but correctly limited to 10 results.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples appear to be missing the outer `<{namespace}:viewFields>` node defined by the `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"` schema. (That or they're missing the inner `<ViewFields>` node in the body of the parameter.)

The `name` properties of the `FieldRef` nodes should be the internal names of the columns.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <ns0:Body>
 <ns1:GetListItems>
      <ns1:listName>{1A8A3DF2-E5D0-4DDE-B31A-CCC2FB7DA90F}</ns1:listName>
      <ns1:viewFields>
          <ViewFields>
              <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
              <FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Description"/>
              <FieldRef Name="Style_x0020_number_x0020_quantit"/>
              <FieldRef Name="Requirement"/>
              <FieldRef Name="First_x0020_order_x0020_entry_x0"/>
              <FieldRef Name="MKT_x0020__x0025__x0020_Completi"/>
              <FieldRef Name="MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"/>
         </ViewFields>
      </ns1:viewFields>
      <ns1:rowLimit>10</ns1:rowLimit>
   </ns1:GetListItems>
 </ns0:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Note that the response will include system columns (such as Title, ID, and Created/Modified) in the results, even if you didn't specify them in the `ViewFields`.

Comment: Which field should I use for the name?  Here's a sample from one of the fields.

_RowOrdinal = "0"  
_DisplayName = "MFG %Completion"  
_Name = "MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"  
_SourceID = "{62606aad-875b-428d-b248-517d564a6e53}"  
_ColName = "float4"  
_StaticName = "MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"  
_Type = "Number"  
_ID = "{111e8dae-2af3-4ea0-aa3f-c72560e68a77}"

Comment: You'll always want to use the field's internal name. In that example, it would be `MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion` from the `_Name` field. If you're not sure which field is breaking the query, you can try adding one `FieldRef` node at a time to the `ViewFields` and executing it each time.

Comment: Still no luck.  If the field I use is in the default view, I get the whole default view.  If it's not, I get an error.  Here's an example of the field section:
`<ns1:viewFields>
     <ViewFields>
         <FieldRef Name="MFG_x0020__x0025_Completion"/>
     </ViewFields>
 </ns1:viewFields>`
Using this field causes the request to time out.  I know the name is valid though.